# Position of window in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i have simple question: How to get position of window on screen in cocoa?
I try using frame from NSWindow but in result i have x and y of window always 0, but my window isn't on this position.

Best regards
Chudziutki

Answer (score 1):

> How to get position of window on screen in cocoa?

Send it a `frame` message and look at the result's `origin` member.

> I try using frame from NSWindow but in result i have x and y of window always 0, but my window isn't on this position.

You forgot to hook up the outlet to your window, so you're sending that `frame` message to `nil`.

Frankly, it's surprising that the frame rectangle makes any sense at all instead of being a geometrically-impossible random set of numbers. Messages to `nil` return 0 for scalar types, such as pointers and single numbers, but a message that returns a structure (such as a rectangle) is not guaranteed to return anything.

Or you're talking to the wrong window—perhaps you created one in a nib and then created another one in code.

Comment: IIRC, structures small enough to fit into some integral type are treated as integers in the context of how a value is returned.